# 3D SLAM without IMU possible?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I'm very new to ros and working on the same problem of building 3d map using lidar but i don't have imu. can you please tell me is it possible to build 3d map without imu? and for that what is the procedure.

I have pioneer 3at robot with ros jade version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224517/3d-slam-without-imu-possible?/) by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This depends on your sensor setup. If it can provide 3D-pointclouds at a high enough rate, you can do 3D-SLAM by aligning the pointclouds with an ICP-Algorithm. You can also use the pioneer's wheel odometry to replace the IMU to some extend.

**Edit:**
A good ICP-Variant is the GeneralizedIterativeClosestPoint from [pcl-registration](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/group__registration.html) library.

To create a 3D-Map with a 2D-Sensor (like your Hokuyo), you have to mount the Scanner on a tilt-unit to periodically tilt it up and down. Then PCL can create a pointcloud out of all scans from one full sweep of the scanner.

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2016-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-20**:
Thanks for the reply. The sensor i am using is hokuyo UTM 30 LX. I converted 2d laser data to pointcloud data using pcl library. Now if i move hokuyo in upward direction manually with hands then also z=0 and in rviz i see only 2d scan not 3d scan. Can you plz suggest me what should i do next.

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-20**:
And if the solution is ICP algorithm then from where i can study that?
Thanks

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-22**:
I tried the same using "https://github.com/ras-sight/hratc2016_entry_template/wiki/pointcloud_generator_node" this package but when i run launch file, it is asking for tilting action server. i dont know how to write action server for that so i tried "rostopic pub " to move ptu but it doesnot move.

**Comment by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) on 2016-01-22**:
What kind of ptu with what kind of ros-driver do you use?

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-22**:
I am using PTU-E46 with flir_ptu_ros drivers. I installed this package from git source.

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-27**:
Hi, sorry to disturb you again. I installed loam_continuous package from git source. Also i download data sets provided i.e bagfile and that is running fine in rviz using command rosbag play. but when i connect hokuyo utm 30lx with my laptop and run that package then i am not able to see 3d pointcld

**Comment by [ARCHANA](https://answers.ros.org/users/25663/archana/) on 2016-01-27**:
Also there is no error. Can you please tell me what changes i have to make in that package so as to use it for hokuyo utm-30lx.

**Comment by [asd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32237/asd/) on 2017-10-13**:
ARCHANA I also installed loam but point cloud is displayed only with rviz not with loam. Can u guess a possible reason for that ? it will be of great help thank u